# Update android textview of another activity after the procedure of login from backgroudtask's onpostexecute

Tags: android, textview

main activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etUsername = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.etUsername));
    etPassword = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.etPassword));
    tvRegister = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.tvRegister));
    blogin = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.blogin));
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Registeration.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void login(View view){
    logid=etUsername.getText().toString();
    logpass=etPassword.getText().toString();
    String method="login";//my php script
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, logid, logpass);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = bundle.getString("username");//Tried using intent
    Menu mn=new Menu();
    mn.textView9.setText(message);
}
```

Onpostexecute

```
if(result.contains("Login Successful")) // msg you get from success like "LoginSuccess"
{
    MainActivity mm=new MainActivity();
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx,Menu.class);
    Menu mn=new Menu();
    String username=mm.etUsername.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("username",username);
    ctx.startActivity(i);
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

activity i want the text of login to be displayed

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    i1= (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.i1));
    etUsername=(EditText)(findViewById(R.id.etUsername));
    textView9=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textView9));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your call:

```
        String username = mm.etUsername.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Menu.class)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, username);
        startActivity(intent);
```

reception:

```
        // The detail Activity called via intent.  
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9))
                    .setText(text);
        }
```